# Updating changed files over ftp

Tags: git, ftp, shared-hosting

I use git and I want to update the remote server's files via ftp. How I'll accomplish this? Is there any ftp command or addon for that?

Comment: This is not a git question. For one thing, git does not have FTP protocol support. For another, you're not even describing using git to push updates to a repository. You're just talking about setting up some kind of automated FTP mechanism. Add much more detail to your question.

Comment: Just before pushing the updated files to the repository git can see the changed files, can't it? I remember that I saw addon for that, but it might me in another version control system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if Git does not support FTP, several tools exist for this :

- [git-ftp](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp) (shell script)

> I use git-ftp for my script based projects, mostly PHP. Most of the
>   low-cost web hoster does not provide SSH nor git support, only FTP.
>
> That is why I needed a easy way to deploy my git tracked projects.
>   Instead to transfer always the whole project, I thought, why not only
>   transfer the files which changed since the last time, git can tell me
>   those files.
>
> Even if you are playing with different branches, git-ftp knows which
>   files are different. No ordinary FTP client can do that.

- [git-ftp](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp) (python script)

> Some web hosts only give you FTP access to the hosting space, but you
>   would still like to use Git to version the contents of your directory.
>   You could upload a full tarball of your website every time you update
>   but that's wasteful. git-ftp.py only uploads the files that changed.

Those scripts only transfer files that have changed since the last time, which is better than nothing.